# Getting 'compileFlutterBuildDebug' error when trying to run Flutter app in Android Studio - how to troubleshoot?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, flutter-run

I am having trouble running my app on android studio as it keeps giving me 'compileFlutterBuildDebug' exception.

..

> /AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/theme_provider-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/theme_dialog.dart:104:30:
> Error: The getter 'accentColor' isn't defined for the class
> 'ThemeData'.

```
'ThemeData' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/theme_data.dart' ('../flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'accentColor'.
: theme.data.accentColor,
^^^^^^^^^^^
../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/theme_provider-0.5.0/lib/src/data/app_theme.dart:109:9: Error: No named parameter with the name 'accentColor'.
accentColor: Colors.pink,
^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/ui/views/ib/syntaxes/ib_md_tag_syntax.dart:10:43: Error: The argument type 'Line' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.
'Line' is from 'package:markdown/src/line.dart' ('../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/git/markdown-bd6ae8d741327e24319f3e036d57107f91229843/lib/src/line.dart').
var match = pattern.firstMatch(parser.current);
^
lib/ui/views/ib/syntaxes/ib_md_tag_syntax.dart:24:36: Error: The argument type 'Line' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.
'Line' is from 'package:markdown/src/line.dart' ('../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/git/markdown-bd6ae8d741327e24319f3e036d57107f91229843/lib/src/line.dart').
return md.Element.text('h5', text);
^
lib/ui/views/ib/syntaxes/ib_liquid_syntax.dart:9:43: Error: The argument type 'Line' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.
'Line' is from 'package:markdown/src/line.dart' ('../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/git/markdown-bd6ae8d741327e24319f3e036d57107f91229843/lib/src/line.dart').
var match = pattern.firstMatch(parser.current);
^
lib/ui/views/ib/syntaxes/ib_embed_syntax.dart:11:38: Error: The argument type 'Line' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.
'Line' is from 'package:markdown/src/line.dart' ('../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/git/markdown-bd6ae8d741327e24319f3e036d57107f91229843/lib/src/line.dart').
return md.Element.text('iframe', text);
^
lib/ui/views/ib/builders/ib_webview_builder.dart:18:20: Error: 'RenderContext' isn't a type.
widget: (RenderContext context, _) {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/ui/views/ib/builders/ib_webview_builder.dart:16:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'customRenders'.
customRenders: {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_html-3.0.0-beta.2/lib/flutter_html.dart:49:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
Html({
^^^^
../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.6.3+1/lib/src/widgets/selection/gesture_detector_builder.dart:186:20: Error: The argument type 'void Function(TapDownDetai
ls)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragDownDetails)?'.
'TapDownDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart' ('../flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/tap.dart').
'TapDragDownDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart' ('../flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart').
onTapDown: onTapDown,
^
../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.6.3+1/lib/src/widgets/selection/gesture_detector_builder.dart:190:24: Error: The argument type 'void Function(TapUpDetails
)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragUpDetails)?'.
'TapUpDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart' ('../flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/tap.dart').
'TapDragUpDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart' ('../flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart').
onSingleTapUp: onSingleTapUp,
^
../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.6.3+1/lib/src/widgets/selection/gesture_detector_builder.dart:195:26: Error: The argument type 'void Function(TapDownDetai
ls)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragDownDetails)?'.
'TapDownDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart' ('../flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/tap.dart').
'TapDragDownDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart' ('../flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart').
onDoubleTapDown: onDoubleTapDown,
^
../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.6.3+1/lib/src/widgets/selection/gesture_detector_builder.dart:196:31: Error: The argument type 'void Function(DragStartDet
ails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragStartDetails)?'.
'DragStartDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/drag_details.dart' ('../flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/drag_details.dart').
'TapDragStartDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart' ('../flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart').
onDragSelectionStart: onDragSelectionStart,
^
../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.6.3+1/lib/src/widgets/selection/gesture_detector_builder.dart:197:32: Error: The argument type 'void Function(DragStartDet
ails, DragUpdateDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragUpdateDetails)?'.
'DragStartDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/drag_details.dart' ('../flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/drag_details.dart').
'DragUpdateDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/drag_details.dart' ('../flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/drag_details.dart').
'TapDragUpdateDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart' ('../flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart').
onDragSelectionUpdate: onDragSelectionUpdate,
^
../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.6.3+1/lib/src/widgets/selection/gesture_detector_builder.dart:198:29: Error: The argument type 'void Function(DragEndDetai
ls)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragEndDetails)?'.
'DragEndDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/drag_details.dart' ('../flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/drag_details.dart').
'TapDragEndDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart' ('../flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart').
onDragSelectionEnd: onDragSelectionEnd,
^
lib/ui/views/ib/builders/ib_interaction_builder.dart:39:22: Error: The method 'WebView' isn't defined for the class 'IbInteractionBuilder'.
'IbInteractionBuilder' is from 'package:mobile_app/ui/views/ib/builders/ib_interaction_builder.dart' ('lib/ui/views/ib/builders/ib_interaction_builder.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'WebView'.
child: WebView(
^^^^^^^
lib/ui/views/ib/builders/ib_interaction_builder.dart:47:48: Error: The method 'runJavascriptReturningResult' isn't defined for the class 'WebViewController'.
'WebViewController' is from 'package:webview_flutter/src/webview_controller.dart' ('../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/webview_flutter-4.2.1/lib/src/webview_controller.dart')
```

.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'runJavascriptReturningResult'.
await _webViewController.runJavascriptReturningResult(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/ui/views/ib/builders/ib_interaction_builder.dart:51:33: Error: The getter 'JavascriptMode' isn't defined for the class 'IbInteractionBuilder'.
'IbInteractionBuilder' is from 'package:mobile_app/ui/views/ib/builders/ib_interaction_builder.dart' ('lib/ui/views/ib/builders/ib_interaction_builder.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'JavascriptMode'.
javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Script 'C:\Users\ainn\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1201

**What went wrong:**

> Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
>
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\ainn\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat''
> finished with non-zero exit value 1
>
> Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with
> --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

**I have tried running the below steps:**

> flutter channel stable flutter upgrade --force flutter pub cache
> repair cd flutter clean flutter run

**Flutter Doctor output:**

> PS C:\Users\ainn\mobile_app_aish> flutter doctor -v [√] Flutter
> (Channel stable, 3.10.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version
> 10.0.19045.2965], locale en-IN) • Flutter version 3.10.3 on channel stable at C:\Users\ainn\flutter\flutter • Upstream repository
> https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git • Framework revision f92f441 (3
> days ago), 2023-06-01 18:17:33 -0500 • Engine revision 2a3401c9bb •
> Dart version 3.0.3 • DevTools version 2.23.1
>
> [√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or
> higher)
>
> [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
> version 33.0.2) • Android SDK at
> C:\Users\ainn\AppData\Local\Android\sdk • Platform android-33,
> build-tools 33.0.2 • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android
> Studio\jbr\bin\java • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
> 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-9586694) • All Android licenses accepted.
>
> [√] Chrome - develop for the web • Chrome at C:\Program
> Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
>
> [√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022
> 17.6.2) • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community • Visual Studio Community 2022 version
> 17.6.33723.286 • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22000.0
>
> [√] Android Studio (version 2022.2) • Android Studio at C:\Program
> Files\Android\Android Studio • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
> https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter • Dart plugin can be
> installed from: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart • Java
> version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-9586694)
>
> [√] VS Code (version 1.78.2) • VS Code at
> C:\Users\ainn\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code • Flutter
> extension version 3.66.0
>
> [√] Connected device (4 available) • sdk gphone x86 64 (mobile) •
> emulator-5554 • android-x64 • Android 13 (API 33) (emulator) • Windows
> (desktop) • windows • windows-x64 • Microsoft Windows [Version
> 10.0.19045.2965] • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 114.0.5735.91 • Edge (web) • edge • web-javascript • Microsoft
> Edge 114.0.1823.37
>
> [√] Network resources • All expected network resources are available.
>
> • No issues found!

I am expecting to run my app in the virtual mobile device which i have connected through emulator.